Get 2 Pie charts in the Same Kernel Outcome
Edited text. I have the pie charts now below each other without the weird empty subplot. Using the same csv file(splitting in 2 csv did not change anything after fixing the code as far I have it now.
But I am still unable to place them side by side.
Does anyone have an idea? I tried to here and there the logic for line,scatter plots show 2 besides each other, but did not work.
Updated Code
ax1 = fig1,(ax1)=plt.subplots(1,figsize=(6,4))

#Top 10 Most Worked with Databases + Pie Chart
ax1=palette_color = sns.color_palette("husl")
ax1=df_databeses_work_with=df_survey_2024['DatabaseHaveWorkedWith'].value_counts()[:10].plot.pie( 
rot=0,title='Top 10 Currently Most used Databases',colors=palette_color,autopct='%.0f%%', labeldistance=1.0)
ax1 = df_databeses_work_with

ax2 = fig2,(ax2)= plt.subplots(1,figsize=(6,4))

#Top 10 Wish to Work/learn Databases + Pie Chart
ax2=palette_color = sns.color_palette("husl")
ax2=df_databeses_wish_work=df_survey_2024['DatabaseWantToWorkWith'].value_counts()[:10].plot.pie(
rot=0,title='Top 10 wish to use/learn Databases',colors=palette_color,autopct='%.0f%%', labeldistance=1.0)
ax2 = df_databeses_wish_work
ax1,ax2

I have looked on google on stack overflow I found 1 code from 2022, I tried to implement part, but is not fully working. Tried GridSpec, swapping the fig comments around. tried to set rows, column (nrows=1, ncols=1) with various values, did not work either. See new image attachedenter image description here
